# Pandas time subset time series - dates ABOVE certain time

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, time-series

If `df[:'2012-01-07']` returns the sub-DataFrame with dates below `20120107`, what does return dates *above* 20120107? `df['2012-01-07':]` doesn't...

Comment: Really? What does it return?

Comment: Post raw data and code that demonstrates this, it works fine for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it works perfect, but maybe in real data need sort index by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,5,4]}, index=pd.date_range('2012-01-05', periods=5))
print (df)

#if need ascending sorting
df = df.sort_index()
            a
2012-01-05  0
2012-01-06  1
2012-01-07  2
2012-01-08  5
2012-01-09  4

print (df[:'2012-01-07'])
            a
2012-01-05  0
2012-01-06  1
2012-01-07  2

print (df['2012-01-07':])
            a
2012-01-07  2
2012-01-08  5
2012-01-09  4
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,5,4]}, index=pd.date_range('2012-01-05', periods=5))

#descending sorting
df = df.sort_index(ascending=False)

print (df)
            a
2012-01-09  4
2012-01-08  5
2012-01-07  2
2012-01-06  1
2012-01-05  0

print (df[:'2012-01-07'])
            a
2012-01-09  4
2012-01-08  5

print (df['2012-01-07':])
            a
2012-01-07  2
2012-01-06  1
2012-01-05  0
```